# Forward Converter analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, converter

I am having difficulties in finding the DC component of the voltage across capacitor C2 expressed in terms of Vg and duty cycle D. In the first interval (DTs) the current through C2 is zero, hence the voltage Vc2 is zero. My problem is when analyzing it during the second interval (D'Ts). The voltage across Vc2 has to be ramping up or down but I have no idea how to proceed from there. I can't seem to apply charge balance to that cap. Please help. TIA!
[image]
[image]

Comment: Ask yourself, what voltage across C2 would satisfy things and ensure that the primary didn't walk into saturation. Think volt-second balance.

Comment: @Andyaka I know the role of C2 is to reset the transformer and for it to do that function the voltage across C2 has to be ramping down negatively? Is that correct? If that is so, how would I use that fact to proceed to the solution? Can we even use volt-sec to a capacitor? I was taught it can only be used to inductors.

Comment: 1st assumption is wrong Ic=0=CdV/dt not Vc=0 when C is closed or opened with residual V

Comment: How about if C2 was large enough so that any ramping was virtually flat?

Comment: Vc2 Ramps up but since +- is inverted appears negative when FET and ab closes so voltage source shunts parallel LC resonator, then if FET opens it becomes high Q LC series resonator and if ab opens you get As Flyback. amp-seconds or 1/2LI^2 ideal in a non saturating choke

Comment: I'm confused. If there is no current flowing through C2 during the first interval, the voltage across it should be zero right? assuming zero initial conditions for Vc2. Why do you say Vc is not zero?

Comment: I still don't get it. Do I need to graph Vc2?

Comment: @Paumdrdo what was voltage when switch closed ? If you assumed 0 then it’s 0